# Google Authorship mark ups are perfectly implemented but not appearing on SERP

Tags: seo, microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

I have implemented Google Authorship mark ups to pages like these (http://www.projectweavers.com/our-blog/) of my website and its been more than 2 weeks but still my website is not appearing with Authorship Snippets on SERP.

When i test my pages on Rich Snippet testing tool, then it shows perfect results. I am not able to figure out what could be the issue in this?

Testing Tool Link: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://www.projectweavers.com/our-blog/&view=

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because your markup is valid doesn't mean Google will show your authorship information. It is at their discretion whether or not it will be displayed and when. This applies to all microdata schemas, sitelinks, etc.

FYI, it took a while for my authorship to show in Google's search but it did eventually happen. If your markup is valid then don't change anything and just wait it out. Making unnecessary changes at this point might set you back and make it take longer for your authorship to be displayed.